Connecting Laravel with Firebase (Realtime Database or Firestore)
I'm trying to connect a Laravel web application to Firebase, but I've run into difficulties. Specifically, I followed a tutorial and installed the necessary package (kreait/laravel-firebase), but I’m unable to establish a connection.
Steps I’ve Taken:
1.Created a new Laravel project:laravel new fyp_firebase
2.Installed the kreait/laravel-firebase package:composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
3.Downloaded the Firebase Service Account JSON key from the Firebase Console (Settings → Service Accounts → Generate New Private Key).
4.Configured the .env file to add Firebase credentials:FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/firebase-service-account.json
5.Published the Firebase configuration to configure the package: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Kreait\Laravel\Firebase\ServiceProvider"
6.Configured config/firebase.php: The Firebase config file was automatically generated, and I updated it to include the correct path to the Firebase service account key:
return [
    'credentials' => env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS'),
    // other settings like database URL
];

What’s Not Working:
I tried calling Firebase methods in my controller, such as interacting with Firebase's Realtime Database, but it’s not connecting.
For example, I have this code in my controller:
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

public function testFirebaseConnection()
{
    $firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(env('FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS'));

    $database = $firebase->createDatabase();
    $ref = $database->getReference('users');
    
    $snapshot = $ref->getSnapshot();
    dd($snapshot->getValue());
}

What I’ve Tried:

I followed this YouTube tutorial, but it didn’t resolve my issue.

I made sure the JSON service account file is in the correct location and updated the .env file with the correct path.

I checked the Firebase project settings, and everything seems to be fine.


What I Expect:
I want to be able to connect to Firebase's Realtime Database or Firestore from my Laravel app and perform basic operations like reading and writing data.
